Lilypond: Guitar stringNumber colliding with glissando
I'd like to tweak (raise) the fingeringNumber '2' in measure 1 just a bit to avoid collision with the glissando. I know how to lower the glissando endpoint, but that's not what I'm after.
Can somebody show me how to do this?


You can do this using Y-offset:
{
  \partial 4
  \set fingeringOrientations = #'(left)
  \set strokeFingerOrientations = #'(right)
  <b-2-\rightHandFinger 1>\glissando
  <e'-\tweak Y-offset 1 -2 e>2.\arpeggio
}

Alternatively you could also add additional padding to the glissando endpoint, so the glissando stops a bit earlier:
\override Glissando.bound-details.right.padding = 3


That helped me on my way, thanks. I was aware of the padding but didn't want to do that. Your    <e'-\tweak Y-offset 1 -2 e>2.\arpeggio    resulted in an error, but after some more ... tweaking, the following was working: *<e\tweak Y-offset -1 1-2\5 e,>2\arpeggio_( *
